# list to float erlang without affecting fractional part

Tags: erlang

I want to convert a `list` number to a `float`. It should not affect its fractional part.
eg.

```
  "1.000"  --> 1.000
```

It should not be 1.0. As well as it should not affect any other values with different format like `"1.23", "8344343.44333330", "34.0",` etc.

`list_to_float` does not work for that as it changes the fractions

```
  1> list_to_float("1.34440").           
  1.3444
```

Comment: Tell me, how exactly _float_ 1.0 and _float_ 1.00 are different?

Comment: @raina77ow - They are not different of course. But I need that to display on the template.(Actually it is customer requirement). But in the mongo collection we store that as a float value.

Comment: You won't be able to differentiate between `1.0` and `1.00` - it's the same number, and `float` type is about _numbers_. What you can differentiate between is their representations - lists, that is. How about adjusting a template instead?

Comment: @raina77ow-Thanks for reply. Not sure that will work. We will have to remember somewhere, that number of zeroes has inputted by user. Probably we would need to change collection type from float to list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Summarizing comments by @raina77ow)

Floats `1.0` and `1.00` correspond to the *same* number, so they cannot (and should not) be stored in a way that preserves the different representation. If you need to preserve the original representation given by a user, you need to store this field as a list (string) and convert to a float whenever you need the float value.

Answer (score 5):

When you do

```
1> list_to_float("1.34440").
1.3444
```

in the shell you are seeing **two** things: first the call to `list_to_float/1` converts the string to a float; then the shell prints the float in its (the shell's) default format. If you want to **print** a float with a specific format the easiest way is to use the `io_lib:format/2` function which gives you control over the formatting and returns the result as a, possibly deep, string. This string can be flattened with `lists:flatten/1`. For a description of the parameters to `io_lib:float/2` look in the documentation [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-2) of the `io` module.

The `io` module uses the `io_lib` module internally.